# Can I code an app that share a music stream on Iphone ( using the phone as a router )

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, router

I'm an novice apple developper, actually working on Ios project for iOS 9 on xcode. I'm working as a freelance for a client, and this client needs an app to stream music.

This app must be capable to share music, it means :

A user has a music on his phone and turn on the "share mode", wich enable other users around him to connect to his iPhone and listen to the same music.

So my question is, can i do that in therms of code ? (turn on router on my iphone, allows connections from other phone ( even if its not an iphone ) and then send the music ( the music stream ).

It may be a too much technical question for this community, but i don't know in wihch stack community post it.

Thanks for any anwer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. I'd recommend checking out the Multipeer Connectivity framework from apple. You can do exactly what you're asking about. The link below talks about your exact scenario - in objective-c, but it works the same way in swift.

https://robots.thoughtbot.com/streaming-audio-to-multiple-listeners-via-ios-multipeer-connectivity

Comment: Nice thank you, it seems to do the work between apple produts, so i should be able to stream music. It might be more difficult if its not an apple device. Thanks anyway